# Two much distance between figure generated by tikz and the caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
%\pagestyle{empty}
    \definecolor{qqzzqq}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
    \definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0.,0.}
    \definecolor{ffffqq}{rgb}{1.,1.,0.}
    \definecolor{ffqqff}{rgb}{1.,0.,1.}
    \definecolor{zzccff}{rgb}{0.6,0.8,1.}
    \definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-1.9327172822357122,-2.1796167757229585) rectangle (5.742291270318256,5.495391776830984);
    \fill[color=zzccff,fill=zzccff,fill opacity=0.20000000298023224] (0.,0.) -- (1.,0.) -- (1.,1.) -- (0.,1.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (1.,0.) -- (2.,0.) -- (2.,1.) -- (1.,1.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.,1.) -- (2.,1.) -- (2.,0.) -- (3.,0.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (4.,1.) -- (3.,1.) -- (3.,0.) -- (4.,0.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (1.,1.) -- (1.5,1.) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.,1.5) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (2.,1.) -- (2.,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,1.) -- (1.,1.) -- (1.,2.) -- (0.,2.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,2.) -- (1.,2.) -- (1.,3.) -- (0.,3.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (1.,2.) -- (2.,2.) -- (2.,3.) -- (1.,3.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,3.) -- (1.,3.) -- (1.,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (1.,3.) -- (2.,3.) -- (2.,4.) -- (1.,4.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (2.,3.) -- (3.,3.) -- (3.,4.) -- (2.,4.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.,3.) -- (4.,3.) -- (4.,4.) -- (3.,4.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=ffqqff,fill=ffqqff,fill opacity=0.550000011920929] (2.,2.) -- (3.,2.) -- (3.,3.) -- (2.,3.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.,2.) -- (4.,2.) -- (4.,3.) -- (3.,3.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.,1.) -- (4.,1.) -- (4.,2.) -- (3.,2.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=ffffqq,fill=ffffqq,fill opacity=0.75] (2.,1.) -- (2.5,1.) -- (2.5,1.5) -- (2.,1.5) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (2.5,1.) -- (3.,1.) -- (3.,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=ccqqqq,fill=ccqqqq,fill opacity=0.75] (2.,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) -- (2.5,2.) -- (2.,2.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=ffffqq,fill=ffffqq,fill opacity=0.75] (2.5,1.5) -- (3.,1.5) -- (3.,2.) -- (2.5,2.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=xdxdff,fill=xdxdff,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (1.,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,2.) -- (1.,2.) -- cycle;
    \fill[color=qqzzqq,fill=qqzzqq,fill opacity=0.5] (1.5,1.5) -- (2.,1.5) -- (2.,2.) -- (1.5,2.) -- cycle;
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,0.)-- (1.,0.);
    \draw [color=zzccff] (1.,0.)-- (1.,1.);
    \draw [color=zzccff] (1.,1.)-- (0.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,1.)-- (0.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,0.)-- (2.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,0.)-- (2.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,1.)-- (1.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,1.)-- (1.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,1.)-- (2.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,1.)-- (2.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,0.)-- (3.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,0.)-- (3.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,1.)-- (3.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,1.)-- (3.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,0.)-- (4.,0.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,0.)-- (4.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,1.)-- (1.5,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,1.)-- (1.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,1.5)-- (1.,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,1.5)-- (1.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,1.)-- (2.,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,1.5)-- (1.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,1.5)-- (1.5,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,1.)-- (2.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,1.)-- (1.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,1.)-- (1.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,2.)-- (0.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,2.)-- (0.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,2.)-- (1.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,2.)-- (1.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,3.)-- (0.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,3.)-- (0.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,2.)-- (2.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,2.)-- (2.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,3.)-- (1.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,3.)-- (1.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,3.)-- (1.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,3.)-- (1.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,4.)-- (0.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (0.,4.)-- (0.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,3.)-- (2.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,3.)-- (2.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,4.)-- (1.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,4.)-- (1.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,3.)-- (3.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,3.)-- (3.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,4.)-- (2.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.,4.)-- (2.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,3.)-- (4.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,3.)-- (4.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,4.)-- (3.,4.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,4.)-- (3.,3.);
    \draw [color=ffqqff] (2.,2.)-- (3.,2.);
    \draw [color=ffqqff] (3.,2.)-- (3.,3.);
    \draw [color=ffqqff] (3.,3.)-- (2.,3.);
    \draw [color=ffqqff] (2.,3.)-- (2.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,2.)-- (4.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,2.)-- (4.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,3.)-- (3.,3.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,3.)-- (3.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,1.)-- (4.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,1.)-- (4.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (4.,2.)-- (3.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,2.)-- (3.,1.);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.,1.)-- (2.5,1.);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.5,1.)-- (2.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.5,1.5)-- (2.,1.5);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.,1.5)-- (2.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.5,1.)-- (3.,1.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,1.)-- (3.,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (3.,1.5)-- (2.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (2.5,1.5)-- (2.5,1.);
    \draw [color=ccqqqq] (2.,1.5)-- (2.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=ccqqqq] (2.5,1.5)-- (2.5,2.);
    \draw [color=ccqqqq] (2.5,2.)-- (2.,2.);
    \draw [color=ccqqqq] (2.,2.)-- (2.,1.5);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.5,1.5)-- (3.,1.5);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (3.,1.5)-- (3.,2.);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (3.,2.)-- (2.5,2.);
    \draw [color=ffffqq] (2.5,2.)-- (2.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,1.5)-- (1.5,1.5);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,1.5)-- (1.5,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.5,2.)-- (1.,2.);
    \draw [color=xdxdff] (1.,2.)-- (1.,1.5);
    \draw [color=qqzzqq] (1.5,1.5)-- (2.,1.5);
    \draw [color=qqzzqq] (2.,1.5)-- (2.,2.);
    \draw [color=qqzzqq] (2.,2.)-- (1.5,2.);
    \draw [color=qqzzqq] (1.5,2.)-- (1.5,1.5);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,1.) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.5,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.5,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (0.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (0.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (0.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,4.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,3.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (4.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.5,1.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.5,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.5,1.5) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.5,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (3.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.5,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.5,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (2.,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (1.5,2.) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (-9.180327762539031E-4,1.001500354284914) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (0.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{bla bla}
\label{fig:bla}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Remove the `\clip` line (the first line after `\begin{tikzpicture}`).

Comment: This seems like code generated by GeoGebra, which always adds a silly `\clip` instruction.

Comment: @gernot an answer? Perhaps you know how to avoid this in Geogebra?

Comment: @Symbol1 I've added an answer. Until egreg's comment I had never heard of GeoGebra, so I have no idea how it happened that the clipping rectangle became larger than the occupied area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
\clip(-1.9327172822357122,-2.1796167757229585) rectangle (5.742291270318256,5.495391776830984);
```

It specifies the area to which the image is trimmed, cutting away everything outside (more precisely only the parts of the image following the line are affected). Without the line, the image will occupy the space actually needed. For some reason unknown to me GeoGebra made the clipping rectangle *larger* than the area occupied by the image.

In the picture below the boxes mark the boundary of the images. The left image is with the clip command, the right one without.

[image]